# Android: How to retrieve the int value of a specified id stated in String?

Tags: android

The following is not compiling and there is no method in the R class which accepts a string of id and returns its corresponding int value. Here, checkBoxName is an array of String.

```
int id = "R.id."+checkBoxName[i];
```

Comment: Although I have to say-  if you think you need to do this, you're probably doing something very wrong.

Comment: You could try to do this by using reflection.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan Then what you are saying is that I should have a variable for each object?